# How to make grouping tighter on ggplot2 geom_jitter?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Attempting to repurpose code for political survey I found on reddit for much smaller sample size.

I am creating a scatterplot using geom_jitter. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(sae, aes(Alignment, Abortion))+
geom_jitter(aes(color = "green"), size = 4, alpha = 0.6)+
labs("Alignment", "Stance on Abortion")
```

Here is the graph it gives:[image]

How do I make the grouping around the "Pro-choice" or the "Pro-life" lines tighter? I believe this current graph would confuse many people as to which observations are pro-choice or pro-life.

Extra credit for helping with the color problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bigger problem. The x-axis is ordered alphabetically, which is very confusing and probably not what you intended. Also, you probably need to specify both the `width` (jitter in x-direction) and `height` (jitter in y direction).

You can fix the ordering using, e.g.,

```
sae$Alignment <- factor(sae$Alignment, levels=unique(sae$Alignment))
```

as demonstrated below.

```
# make up some data - you have this already
set.seed(1)     # for reproducible example
sae <- data.frame(Alignment=rep(c("Left","Left Leaning","Center","Right Leaning","Right"),each=5),
                  Abortion =sample(c("Pro Choice","Pro Life","Other"),25, replace=TRUE))

# you start here...
library(ggplot2)
sae$Alignment <- factor(sae$Alignment, levels=unique(sae$Alignment))
ggplot(sae, aes(Alignment, Abortion))+
  geom_point(color = "green", size = 4, alpha = 0.6, position=position_jitter(width=0.1, height=0.1))+
  labs("Alignment", "Stance on Abortion")
```

[image]

Also, IMO, you could do better viz. colors:

```
sae$Orientation <- with(sae,ifelse(grepl("Left",Alignment),"Progressive",
                                   ifelse(grepl("Right",Alignment),"Conservative","Neutral")))
ggplot(sae, aes(x=Alignment, y=Abortion, color=Orientation))+ 
  geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.6, position=position_jitter(width=0.1, height=0.1))+
  labs("Alignment", "Stance on Abortion")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `width` parameter in `position = position_jitter()` to control how tight the points are.

```
ggplot(sae, aes(Alignment, Abortion)) +
    geom_jitter(color = "green", size = 4, alpha = 0.6, position = position_jitter(width = .2)) +
    labs("Alignment", "Stance on Abortion")
```

If you're using the newest development version of ggplot2 (1.0.1.9003), you can just do `geom_jitter(width = .2, ...)` instead.

If it's still too wide, decrease `width` to a smaller value (and vice versa). Also note that to change the color of the points, I removed the `aes()` around `color = "green"`.

Comment: Specifying `width=...` directly in the call to `geom_jitter(...)` doesn't work (for me anyway...). You need to do something like `geom_jitter(..., position=position_jitter(width=...))`. See the examples in [the documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_jitter.html).

Comment: @jlhoward Aha: this [changed in one of the more recent versions of ggplot2](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1116). Looks like the [1.0.0 release](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/releases/tag/v1.0.0). Edited answer, thanks!

Comment: I see what you mean by the fix, but I just downloaded the latest version on CRAN (1.0.1) and it still doesn't work. Is this a development version you're using?

Comment: @jlhoward You are right: my mistake. I'm using ggplot2 `1.0.1.9003`- thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1):

Having hit this problem just recently, none of the answers above give an optimal solution.

I found an elegant answer using geom_beeswarm in library(geom_beeswarm) and thought I'd post it here.

Reproducing with geom_jitter using mpg is fairly messy:

```
data(mpg)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cyl, y=hwy, group=factor(cyl))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(height = .2, width = .2))
```

[image: Jitter]

Whereas geom_beeswarm makes the jitter points centralised and much clearer:

```
library(geom_beeswarm)
data(mpg)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cyl, y=hwy, group=factor(cyl))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_beeswarm()
```

[image: beeswarm]